# Have there been any occurrences of a country automatically joining the European Union after unification/reunification (or tried to)?

Tags: european-union

Written in an article by The Independent [*'Northern Ireland ‘can rejoin EU after Brexit if it votes for reunification'*](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-northern-ireland-can-rejoin-eu-reunification-david-davis-stormont-a7653346.html). A statement from the [Brexit Secretary](https://www.gov.uk/government/people/david-davis) on an Ireland reunification says:

> “If a majority of the people of Northern Ireland were ever to vote to
>   become part of a united Ireland the UK Government will honour its
>   commitment to enable that to happen.”
>
> “In that event, Northern Ireland would be in a position of becoming
>   part of an existing EU member state, rather than seeking to join the
>   EU as a new independent state.”

Have there been any *other* occurrences of (re)unification for membership of the European Union or [its predecessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Community) other than that of the [1990 unification of East and West Germany to join the EEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_reunification), or any *serious* political discussion within a member state about doing so?

Comment: The only other case I know of would be Cyprus and AFAIK there the official position of the EU is that the whole island is already a member of the EU. Reunifications are rare. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder I thought as much, but haven't heard of the Cyprus and AFAIK situation before. I'll look into that.

Comment: Mayotte was French all along but became part of the EU in 2014. Greenland left in 1985 and Saint-Barthélemy left in 2012 (both are now considered “overseas countries and territories”). And as you note, Germany added a big chunk of territory and population in 1990. So territorial reconfigurations are possible.

Comment: @BradleyWilson I think that "AFAIK" is "as far as I know", rather than a country, or a Cypriot group. As far as I know...

Comment: Ah gotcha, never heard of that acronym before.

Answer (score 4):

The only other example I know of is the situation in Cyprus. On accession to the EU in 2003, the northern part of the island was, and remains, *de facto* controlled by Northern Cyprus; a state created after the 1974 invasion by Turkey.

As a consequence, in the [treaty](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:12003T/PRO/10) which set out the state's accession, the EU laid out how the issue would be handled.

In particular, Article 1 suspends the application of the '[acquis](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/summary/glossary/acquis.html)' - and therefore, the EU's *de facto* territory - in areas of Cyprus not effectively controlled by the government, while reserving the right of the Council to withdraw this suspension, presumably on reunification.

> Article 1
>
> 1. The application of the acquis shall be suspended in those areas of the Republic of Cyprus in which the Government of the Republic of
>    Cyprus does not exercise effective control.
> 2. The Council, acting unanimously on the basis of a proposal from the Commission, shall decide on the withdrawal of the suspension referred
>    to in paragraph 1.

Article 4 is also relevant; it allows the European Council, acting unanimously, to alter primary law - the Act of Accession 2003 - in order to provide a simplified procedure to accommodate a reunification or territorial change. A primary law change would usually have to be ratified by all member states.

> Article 4
>
> In the event of a settlement, the Council, acting unanimously on the
> basis of a proposal from the Commission, shall decide on the
> adaptations to the terms concerning the accession of Cyprus to the
> European Union with regard to the Turkish Cypriot Community.

This 'pre-ratification', is as far as I'm aware, the closest example to the Northern Ireland & East Germany situations.